# Reference: Quantum Hall effect

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics

I am currently studying mathematical physics and I wan't some reference on the Quantum Hall effect written for mathematicians, does not assume knowledge of physics and it is more or less self contained i.e. some missing proofs would not be a problem as long as the required theorems are stated or part of a 'standard' course on C*-algebras/von Neumann algebras/etc.